# Fan speed problem in ubuntu

Tags: boot, drivers, fan, temperature, fancontrol

I am using ubuntu latest version for couple of months in my HP EliteBook 8460p, it was working good. But today I turn on my laptop its fan speed goes to high and start making noise soo loud suddenly! even laptop is at normal temperature (few minutes after boot). When I boot my laptop as windows 10 fan working fine. I think that it was the problem in ubuntu. Please let know to solve this problem... Thanks !

Comment: Please be specific with details; if you're using the *latest* release of Ubuntu; it hasn't been out yet for a single month & thus "*couple of months*" makes no sense at all unless you installed it during *alpha* or *beta* stages, so did you?  Were you using a pre-release product? or aren't using the *latest* release? or your details are incorrect,  Please use specific facts, also if using a desktop, server or other.  FYI:  It's currently November 2022, with the latest product being released last month ie. 22.10 (2022-October release) with Desktop, and Server products released, and *flavors*.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `fancontrol` (part of `lm-sensors`) to set fan speed.
The first thing to do is to run
`sensors-detect`.

This will detect all of the sensors present and they will be used for fancontrol.
After that, run the following to check if it detected the sensors correctly:

```
# sensors
```

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:      +29.0°C  (high = +76.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)  
...
fan1:        690 RPM  (min =   10 RPM)
```

Once the sensors are properly configured, use pwmconfig(8) to test and configure fan speed control.
Following the guide should create `/etc/fancontrol`, a customized configuration file.
In the guide, the default answers are in parenthesis if you press enter without typing anything.
Enter `y` for `yes`, `n` for `no`.

```
# pwmconfig
```

See [this Archlinux manual page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/fan_speed_control).

Comment: My motherboard doesn't support pwm. While using "# pwmconfig".